# Element must refer to an existing simple or complex type

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm trying to make an xsd valid. I have this "simple" file

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

<xs:element name="Pairs">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="t1" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="t2" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="Configuration">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="pairs" type="Pairs" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:element name="elems" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I got this error:

```
'Pairs' must refer to an existing simple or complex type.
```

I've already read this post: [Error: Must refer to an existing simple or complex type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36179696/error-must-refer-to-an-existing-simple-or-complex-type) and others, but I still don't understand why I've got this error.

Thank you very much,

S.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the problem in my xsd.
I cannot use

```
<xs:element name="pairs" type="Pairs" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
```

because *Pairs* is not a *type* but it's and *element*.
I can then use a *reference* to an element

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

<xs:element name="Pairs">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="t1" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="t2" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>


<xs:element name="Configuration">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="Pairs" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:element name="elems" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

</xs:schema>

or declare *Pairs* as a *complexType*

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

```
<xs:complexType name="Pairs">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="t1" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="t2" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>


<xs:element name="Configuration">
    <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="pairs" type="Pairs" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <xs:element name="elems" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

</xs:schema>

this last one xsd solves the issue for me.

I hope this answer can be useful.

S.